# Units of parameters in Brownian motion with drift

Tags: stochastic-processes

If I have a simple Brownian motion with drift like that:

$\textrm{d}X_t = \mu\textrm{d}t + \sigma \textrm{d}W_t$

And that the units of X are say apples, the time is in hours, then the units of $\mu$ is apples per hour, but what are the units of $\sigma$ ? square root  of apples per hour ? I'm not sure how to think about it.

Comment: Apples by square root of unit of time.